# Do we know if there is an oracle $B$ so that $P^B \neq NP^B$ but $coNP^B=NP^B$?

Tags: complexity-theory

We know there is $B$ with $P^B \neq NP^B$, and we know there is $C$ with $coNP^C=NP^C$, what happens if we want to mix?

Comment: It sounds very likely that one exists. Have you tried scanning the literature, or coming up with a candidate on your own?

Comment: An oracle relative to which $\mathsf{NP=EXP}$ would to the trick. See theorem 6 in [Heller's](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0213045) paper for the construction.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks, if you write it as an answer I'll accept.
@YuvalFilmus; I tried looking it up without much success, I also didn't think about it much, hoping someone would have an answer.

Answer (score 2):

Any oracle relative to which $\mathsf{NP=EXP}$ would do the trick. You can find a construction of such an oracle in [Heller's](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/10.1137/0213045) paper. Clearly if $\mathsf{NP=EXP}$ then $\mathsf{NP=coNP=EXP}$ but $\mathsf{P\neq NP}$ by the time hierarchy theorem.

I don't know whether there are known oracle constructions who collapse the hierarchy to $\Sigma_i$ and not to $\Sigma_{i-1}$, but it's an interesting question (I would guess the answer is in the affirmative).